# I want to create a plugin using biometric authentication (Biometric) provided by Google and implement it in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins, aar, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt

I would like to implement biometric authentication using the biometrics provided by Googole, but I am having trouble getting it to work.
The following is a reference site on biometrics.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric

I've never made an Android plugin before, and I'm having a hard time finding information on how to integrate with Unity.

I'm testing it with the following code

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/activity/ComponentActivity;
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
```

I'm getting an error and don't know how to fix it.
Please help me. Please help me.

◇MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.biometricslibs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

public class MainActivity {
    public static MainActivity instance() {
        return new MainActivity();
    }

    private Executor executor = new MainThreadExecutor();
    private BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt;

    private BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback callback = new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
            if (errorCode == 13 && biometricPrompt != null)
                biometricPrompt.cancelAuthentication();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
            super.onAuthenticationFailed();
        }
    };

    public void BiometricCheck(Context context) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt((FragmentActivity) context, executor, callback);

        BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("title")
                .setSubtitle("subTitle")
                .setDescription("description")
                .setNegativeButtonText("cancel")
                .build();

        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
    }
}
```

◇MainThreadExecutor.java

```
package com.example.biometricslibs;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

public class MainThreadExecutor implements Executor {

    private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable r) {
        handler.post(r);
    }
}
```

◇UnityC#

```
using(var nativeDialog = new AndroidJavaClass("com.example.biometricslibs.MainActivity"))
        {
            using(var unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
            {
                using(var currentUnityActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
                {
                    using(var instance = nativeDialog.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance"))
                    {
                        instance.Call(
                            "BiometricCheck",
                            currentUnityActivity
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: it's says class not found. Make sure you added all the dependency.

Comment: @Jaimin I've checked. androidx.activity.ComponentActivity has been added.androidx.activity:activity:1.2.4@aar　I've added it.